# Webservice response error: The download of the specified resource has failed

Tags: iis, xmlhttprequest

I have a webservice that is https based. It works fine but some times (randomly), it returns this error: "-21466927208 The download of the specified resource has failed"

When this happens I reset the IIS, and also the service of this webservice. But nothing gets solved. But the most strange is that after a while it solves without doing anything.

Before the call of this webservice, the program makes a call to another webservice non-https, that works perfecly (alltime). So the problem is obviously with the https based webservice.

Im completely lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, there where 2 sites in the same domain so the IIS did the balancer, and therefore sometimes it worked, and sometimes not.

Changing the bindings did the trick.

Hope this can help others!